# How to isolate enums by making a distinction on type?

Tags: python, enums, type-safety

The following code defines two enums

```
class Insect:
    BEE = 0x00
    WASP = 0x01
    BUMBLEBEE = 0x02


class Breakfast:
    HAM = 0x00
    EGGS = 0x01
    PANCAKES = 0x02


b = Insect.WASP
if b == Breakfast.EGGS:
    print("ok")
```

As the condition illustrates, one is left open to make a mistake of testing against an entirely distinct enum. How can I isolate the enums, **by type** not by distinct values, so that the test above will generate an error?

**Update**

I see that this is one of the finer points along the road of moving from Python 2 to Python 3.

Thanks to wim's suggestion, the following code will generate an error if I attempt to compare apples and oranges.

```
from enum import Enum


class Apple(Enum):
    RED_DELICIOUS = 0x00
    GALA = 0x01
    FUJI = 0x02

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(other) is not type(self):
            raise Exception("You can't compare apples and oranges.")
        return super().__eq__(other)


class Orange(Enum):
    NAVEL = 0x00
    BLOOD = 0x01
    VALENCIA = 0x02

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(other) is not type(self):
            raise Exception("You can't compare apples and oranges.")
        return super().__eq__(other)


apple = Apple.GALA
if apple == Orange.BLOOD:
    print("ok")
```

Comment: You haven't created an `Enum`, you created two classes with attributes. Enums are created using the `enum.Enum` type in 3.4+, or using the [`enum34`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) backport for 3.3-, or the [`Advanced Enum library`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) for 2 & 3.  (Disclosure:  I wrote all three.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use a custom class for it.  Use the stdlib's `enum` type, they'll do the right thing here.

```
from enum import Enum

class Insect(Enum):
    ...
```

If you want a hard crash:

```
class MyEnum(Enum):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(other) is not type(self):
            raise Exception("Don't do that")
        return super().__eq__(other)
```

But I caution against this design, since:

1. enum instances are often compared by identity and not equality
2. there is little (no?) precedent in Python for equality comparisons raising errors

Comment: Raising an exception on failed equality tests is (almost?) never a good idea.  `==` should return `True` or `False`, not raise.

Comment: I agree on your design suggestion but the question is tagged `type-safety` and it explicitly asked "*...so that the test above will **generate an error***"

Comment: Ah, I missed that.  Thanks for adding my response to your answer, though.  :)

Answer (score 3):

A few notes on equality testing, why it shouldn't raise exceptions, and proper type testing.

**Why shouldn't `==` raise exceptions?**

Equality testing is used constantly throughout Python, especially in containers: `list`, `dict`, and `set`, to name a few, rely on equality testing to find members, return members, change members, remove members, etc.  If your `Apple` `Enum` raises every time it is compared to a non-`Apple` it will break any container it is added to.

**Correct way for custom types to fail equality tests (and other comparison tests)**

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
        return NotImplented   # note:  NOT RAISE
    ... comparison here ...
```

NB.  The above tests are already built in to the `Enum` type.

**Proper type testing**

If you really, really want to ensure you don't get a type you don't want, and an error should be the result:

```
var1 = ...
if not isinstance(var1, SomeTypeHere):
    raise SomeException
```

But the above code *SHOULD NOT* be in any rich comparison method*.

---

*The rich comparison methods are `__eq__`, `__ne__`, `__ge__`, `__gt__`, `__le__`, and `__lt__`.