# What is the root of the distinction in the meaning of equality between C++ and Python?

Tags: python, c++

There appears to be an almost philosophical difference in the meaning of "equality" between C++ and Python. I [became aware](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49060812/704972) of this distinction through an attempt to do in Python something that is quite difficult in C++: distinguishing between two enum types when they are both just a wrapper for a set of integers, *but the issue is broader than enums*, hence the present question.

If I write in C++ code such as the following

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    bool operator==(const Foo& foo) const { return this == &foo; }
};

struct Bar {};

int main() {
    Foo foo = Foo();
    Bar bar = Bar();
    if (foo == bar) std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
}
```

I fully expect that the equality comparison will fail. Indeed, it's a compilation error. You can't even compare two objects unless they're, just to get going, of the same type.

And yet it appears that 
"[*there is little (no?) precedent in Python for equality comparisons raising errors*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060836/704972)".

and "[*if [an object] raises every time it is compared to a [object of a different type], it will break any container it is added to*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49061174/704972)".

Indeed, writing

```
class Foo(object):
    pass


class Bar(object):
    pass


foo = Foo()
bar = Bar()

if (foo == bar):
    print("equal")
```

reveals that there is no problem in comparing objects that should otherwise be incomparable.

What, philosophically, is the root of this distinction in the meaning of equality between the two languages?

**Update**

Part of my puzzlement at finding this out about Python is that so far every feature appears to have been designed with the intent of being "natural", "intuitive", even "human"—not that these can be defined in the first place.

But consider that you are at the fruit section of a grocery shop and ask one of the aproned chaps: "Could you tell me whether these oranges are Fuji or Red Delicious?" Surely no one could make sense of the question to venture an answer one way or the other. So the question is how to provide a response of "incredulous" in bits and bytes.

**Update 2**

(Too long to be a comment to @GiacomoAlzetta's comment) I respect your opinion. Still, from this point on, I will not respect a book on Python that does not dedicate a chapter, or at least a section, to pointing out that `3 < [1]` is True, and that explains the background (whether historical or philosophical) for this. Being dynamically typed does not mean that one is so very cornered (because, e.g., one has only a handful of available names 'a', 'b', and 'c') to reuse a name for a very different meaning. Ultimately, it's not even a philosophical, but an engineering, issue: How do you remove, or at least reduce, the chance that one among multiple people collaborating on a software project will introduce bugs in the system? Bugs that remain dormant (because the language is dynamically typed—and we cannot predict computation paths) are far worse than bugs that scream "error".

Comment: As this is more of a language design question than a practical problem, it may be a better fit for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: By the way, if you want to live in a world of typed variables and homogeneous collections, you may want to check out [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/).

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the pointer. I've been quite happy with the little bit of rigor that using flycheck in emacs brings to my Python code early on. It's not quite the brutal type checking that a compiler would do, but it accelerates taking strides while coding.

Comment: The case with C++, as with all strongly typed languages, is that it is a natural realization of math. Functions have specific domains, thus comparing two unrelated entity is simply undefined

Comment: In your grocery store example, you're not comparing - you're asking for a classification.  More germane:  even a 5-year-old can tell you correctly that a banana is not a bar of soap.  That's what Python 3 tells you too.  And, also just like the 5-year-old, Python 3 will throw a tantrum if you ask instead whether a banana is greater than a bar of soap ;-)  Equality and inequality are usually crystal clear even when _ordering_ makes no apparent sense.  For a "pure math" case of that, consider complex numbers (which cannot be made an "ordered field" despite that equality is easily defined).

Comment: As it stands in your C++ example, you can't compare equality between two `Foo`s, or two `Bar`s. Even `foo == foo` is an ill formed program. C++ requires you to define the operation

Comment: I see little point in this question. Python is a dynamically typed language. If all operations with different types raised an errors then being dynamically typed would **only** have disadvantages. By allowing some operations to act on different unrelated types you sometimes allow simpler code and code that is written faster than in a statically typed language, and that's precisely the point of a dynamically typed language. Obviously: *some* operations do not make sense in any way you look at them.

Comment: @Calaf C++ does not have default-generated comparison operators (yet?). I believe you're mixing it up with the assignment operators.

Comment: Minimizing the chance of bugs is a good goal, but it is not always an overriding one (for example, we can get the chance of bugs to zero by not writing any code). You may like to read [these remarks on the appeal of dynamically-typed languages](https://gist.github.com/non/ec48b0a7343db8291b92). For the equality-comparison question, suppose you somehow have a list like `[3.14, "whatever", 42, None]`. Now if you write code like `for r in responses: if r != "whatever": …`, you may prefer that to throw an error; others may not. (In many languages it's not even convenient to *create* such a list.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The fundamental intent in Python has changed over time.  At the start, and until late in the development of Python 2, it was essentially the case that *any* two objects could be compared.  Even mixed-type comparisons that made no intuitive sense, like:

```
>>> 3 < [1]
True
```

In cases like that, it was actually the string names of the types that were compared, and the result above was due to that, as strings, `"int" < "list"`.  This was driven mostly by a misguided (in hindsight) attempt to impose a total ordering on all objects.

Looking ahead to Python 3, the intent changed, and started to be implemented with the `datetime` module types (which were introduced in Python 2):  mixed-typed `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=` comparisons that made scant intuitive sense were to raise exceptions instead, while senseless mixed-type `==` would always return `False` and senseless mixed-type `!=` always `True`.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> n = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> n < 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to int
>>> n >= 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to int
>>> n == 3
False
>>> n != 3
True
```

Python 3 strives to act "like that" generally.  Of course there are exceptions.  For example, when comparing objects of different numeric types (like integers and floats), they're usually coerced to a common type under the covers.

I was deeply involved in these decisions (and wrote the `datetime` module), so you can trust me on that.  But as to what `C++` intends, you'll have to ask someone else ;-)

### A Bit More Info

I should add that, up until the introduction of "rich comparisons" in Python 2, all comparisons funneled through a `cmp()` protocol:  in the CPython implementation, comparing two objects returned one of the integers in `[-1, 0, 1]`.  `__cmp__()` methods had no idea which of `<`, `<=`, `==`, `!=`, `>`, and `>=` was actually desired.  So while the "compare any two things no matter what" original design was *disliked* early on, it was technically difficult to get away from before rich comparisons were incorporated into the language.  Then it became straightforward (if tedious).

Comment: Nice answer, complete with historical background. But could you comment on whether you agree or disagree that designing a system in Python that disallows any comparison between different types would introduce problems in the long term, as the opinions I quoted suggest?

Comment: Most container types in Python couldn't care less how wildly you mix types in their contents, and the Python 3 approach allows "the obvious" membership tests to perform as intended no matter how wildly they are in fact mixed.  So did the Python 2 approach, but that also "made up" results for much _more_ than was actually useful for the vast majority of programs.  I believe the Python 3 approach struck the right balance.  But since I contributed to that outcome, of course that's what I would say ;-)

Comment: Good answer. AFAIK, Python 2 could compare any two objects, as long as one of them wasn't a complex number.

Comment: `1j < "hello"` is true in Python 2, but, e.g., `1j < 2j` raises `TypeError`.  The insanity of that ;-) was one more reason Python 3 changed the approach (and they both raise `TypeError`).

Comment: Why "sense-less `==`"? Objects of different types are obviously not equal, so it's completely reasonable that `==` returns `False`. Now, if it was reasonable to try and compare them in the first place — that's a completely different question.

Comment: @Joker_vD, in context I think it's clear enough that "senseless" referred to "lack of a more-than-less obvious _total_ ordering".  "Senseless" was qualifying "mixed-type", not specific comparison operators.

Answer (score 4):

It's not so much a "philosophical" matter as a difference between dynamic language like Python and a strongly-typed language like C++. Because variables can hold any type in Python, and that type can change dynamically, it makes sense for the meaning of equality to be looser in Python than something like C++. You don't want exceptions to be raised because you asked whether two variables were equal - in principle the exception would need to be raised at runtime since Python is interpreted, and in a scripting language you would much prefer the comparison to return false in this circumstance. Similarly you can say something like:

```
if (foo):
    [some code]
```

even though foo is not boolean. So you have the concept of things being "falsey", which is weird from a strongly-typed world perspective, but useful in a scripting context.

In short the philosophical explanation rests on the respective philosophy of dynamic and strongly typed languages.

Comment: C++ has "contextually convertible to bool" as a category of type conversion. `if (someObject)` will perform an *explicit* cast to bool (if one exists)

Comment: @Caleth but you still have to explicitly declare a conversion to `bool`, which most objects don't (and thus can't be "truthy" or "falsy").

Answer (score 3):

I see no one expanded on the C++ side, so here are my two cents.

In C++ every object (and variable) has a definitive type which cannot change, so a type mismatch can be detected at compile-time. Since the result of equality between two unrelated objects is "duh, of course not", and C++ puts high value on detecting errors early, it simply doesn't compile at all.